# How we can pass multiple values in ODI scenarion variables

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

Is there any way to pass the multiple values in odi scenario Variable.

I am attaching the screenshot for the reference.[image]

Comment: Not possible, but you can pass variable values into IN statement if your logic allow.e.g: Values: 'ABC','XYZ' this can be use in IN statement, else you can take value from variable & perform Reg EXPR and store into temp table in database & using Conditional operator in ODI you can run a loop and process each values eveytime.

Comment: You can, if you defined your own KM! In your predefined KM you can split the variable and then use it as you need.

Answer (score 1):

See the Oracle function `listagg`. For example:

```
SELECT 
LISTAGG (
                  [col_value1] || ','
) 
WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY      [col_date] desc
) AS            [col_alias] 
FROM            [table];
```

This would create list of values with comma in between. You could do a semicolon, comma, etc. You could place this in the *Source Command* feeding the *Target Value*, or just show it as immediate output in the *Target Value*.